# How to use multiple client certificates stored in keystore.p12 and set jmeter's system.properties while setting test in Azure Load Testing service?

Tags: azure-devops, jmeter, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-task-lib

I am trying to set up test (manual/yaml) in Azure Load Testing service and my test uses client certificates, so I uploaded jmx, keystore(.p12) and csv (has alias of certificates in keystore) to test plan.

In Azure Load Testing, where can I set javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType, javax.net.ssl.keyStore, javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword, https.use.cached.ssl.context,https.keyStoreStartIndex and https.keyStoreEndIndex properties?

In case of Jmeter, I would set above properties in jmeter's system.properties file. But, in case of Azure Load Testing, not sure how to get this working.

Please suggest, Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Configure a load test in YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/reference-test-config-yaml)

> `configurationFiles` List of relevant configuration files or other files that you reference in the Apache JMeter script. For example, a CSV data set file, images, or any other data file. These files will be uploaded to the Azure Load Testing resource alongside the test script. If the files are in a subfolder on your local machine, use file paths that are relative to the location of the test script.

So my expectation is that if you upload *system.properties* file along with the .jmx script and CSV file with certificate aliases the Azure load testing engine should pick it up and apply.

It should also be possible to do via [GUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/quickstart-create-and-run-load-test#create_test):

[image]

More information: [How to Use Multiple Certificates When Load Testing Secure Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-multiple-certificates-when-load-testing-secure-websites)

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T Thanks for response. I have tried uploading .jmx, keystore.p12, keystore.csv and system.properties files in test plan and after running the test, I checked the log file and it says  followings                                                                                                                             
WARN o.a.j.c.KeystoreConfig: https.use.cached.ssl.context property must be set to false to ensure Multiple Certificates are used
WARN o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Keystore file not found, loading empty keystore

Comment: Azure load testing engine is able to find keystore.csv which is referred in .jmx file but not considering keystore.p12 file because when I checked test run results, in responseMessage, it says "No PrivateKey found for alias: alias_name_here"